# Node.js : Mongodb - Concurrent Requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency

In my node.js application, a route is executed on Ajax request and it always receives concurrent requests.

My requirement is to check for a similar document and if exist upsert the data to existing document. If no similar document then create a new record.

Refer the code given below. The problem is that most times the "findExistingDoc" returns false, but by the time when a call tries to create a new document, a similar document is already created by a previous call.

Please help with a optimal solution to solve this problem.

```
self.findExistingDoc(function(err, doc){    //  Check if a similar doc already exist

    if (!doc){
        console.log ("NO existing doc");                    

        self.save(function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                console.error ("DB Error while creating new doc : " + JSON.stringify(err));
            } else {
                console.log ("New document created");
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log ("existing doc");                   

        var qry = {"name": req.s_name, "class": req.s_class};
        self.model("Collection").findOneAndUpdate (qry,  {$addToSet: {"data": req.body.s_data}}, {safe: true, upsert: true}, function (err, album) {
            if (err) {
                console.error ("DB Error while adding data to existing doc : " + JSON.stringify(err));
            } else {
                console.log ("Data added to existing doc");
            }
            callback(err, output);
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: What is the structure of doc and your s_data from the body

Comment: {
        s_name: "John",
        s_class: "Pre-Univ",
        data: [ { d1: "XYZ"}, {d1: "ABC"} ]
    }

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem after some googling. Thanks to the new "$setOnInsert" operator that's introduced in mongodb v2.4.

```
var slug = getUniqueSlug("name");
var qry = {"name": req.s_name, "class": req.s_class};
var update = {"$addToSet": {"data": req.body.s_data}, "$setOnInsert": {"slug": slug}};
self.model("Collection").findAndModify ( qry, update, {"safe": true, "upsert": true} );
```